# Calculate the last day of the prior quarter

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

What's the most efficient way to calculate the last day of the prior quarter?

Example:  given the date 11/19/2008, I want to return 9/30/2008.

Platform is SQL Server

Comment: What is the desired result for '9/30/2008'? '6/30/2008'?

Comment: yes, and to capture all limits: 10/1/2008 should be 9/30/2008

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If @Date has the date in question

```
Select DateAdd(day, -1, dateadd(qq, DateDiff(qq, 0, @Date), 0))
```

EDIT: Thanks to @strEagle below, simpler still is:

```
Select dateadd(qq, DateDiff(qq, 0, @Date), -1)
```

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines, but I didn't know about the "qq" bits. Makes things a lot easier...

Answer (score 17):

Actually simpler is:

```
SELECT DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), -1)
```

Answer (score 8):

**Get the current date**

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) [Current Date]
```

**Get the 1st date of the quarter for the current date**

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(QQ, DATEDIFF(QQ, 0, GETDATE())  ,0)) [Current Quarter 1st Date]
```

**Get the last date of the quarter for the current date**

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q, 0, GETDATE()) +1, 0))) [Current Quarter Last Date]
```

**Get the 1st date of the next quarter for the current date**

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(QQ, DATEDIFF(QQ, 0, GETDATE()) +1 ,0)) [Next Quarter 1st Date]
```

**Get the last date of the next quarter for the current date**

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q, 0, GETDATE()) +2, 0))) [Next Quarter Last Date]
```

Comment: I think it would be great if you can explain what you have done. Then, more people will be able to understand what you proposed.

Answer (score 3):

I came up with this (tested for all months):

```
select dateadd(dd,-1,dateadd(qq,datediff(qq,0,'11/19/2008'),0)),
       dateadd(dd,-1,dateadd(qq,datediff(qq,0,'10/19/2008'),0)),
       dateadd(dd,-1,dateadd(qq,datediff(qq,0,'12/19/2008'),0))
```

It might turn out to be the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

```
convert(varchar, dateadd(dd,-1,dateadd(qq,1,DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq,0,YOUR_DATE), 0))),112)
```

you also can change 112 base on this below list

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 100) -- mon dd yyyy hh:mmAM (or PM)
                                        -- Oct  2 2008 11:01AM
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 101) -- mm/dd/yyyy - 10/02/2008                  
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 102) -- yyyy.mm.dd – 2008.10.02           
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 103) -- dd/mm/yyyy
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 104) -- dd.mm.yyyy
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 105) -- dd-mm-yyyy
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 106) -- dd mon yyyy
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 107) -- mon dd, yyyy
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 108) --  hh:mm:ss
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 109) -- mon dd yyyy hh:mm:ss:mmmAM (or PM)
                                        -- Oct  2 2008 11:02:44:013AM   
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 110) -- mm-dd-yyyy
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 111) -- yyyy/mm/dd
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 112) -- yyyymmdd
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 113) -- dd mon yyyy hh:mm:ss:mmm
                                        --  02 Oct 2008 11:02:07:577     
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 114) -- hh:mm:ss:mmm(24h)
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 120) -- yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss(24h)
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 121) --  yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 126) -- yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.mmm
                                        --  2008-10-02T10:52:47.513
-- SQL create different date styles with t-sql string functions
SELECT replace(convert(varchar, getdate(), 111), '/', ' ') -- yyyy mm dd
SELECT convert(varchar(7), getdate(), 126)                 -- yyyy-mm
SELECT right(convert(varchar, getdate(), 106), 8)          -- mon yyyy
```

Comment: The question is not about conversion to VARCHAR in any way, just about getting a date that is the end of the quarter.

Comment: yaya, I know but I think will have someone same with me. They also only want to get the last date of a quarter with yyyymmdd format. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

**In amazon redshift:**

Last day of the previous quarter:

```
select dateadd(day,-1,DATE_TRUNC('qtr', current_date)) from whatever
```

Last day of current quarter:

```
select dateadd(qtr,1,dateadd(day,-1,DATE_TRUNC('qtr', current_date))) from whatever
```

Comment: The platform is SQL Server. `DATE_TRUNC` is not supported.