# Retrieve data quarterly(each 3 month) and also show last day of quarter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have a problem, i cant get the sum for quarterly data.

I want my output like this:

```
@startdate='5/17/2017'
```

and

```
@enddate='5/27/2017
```

output:

```
AccountNo     06/30/2017
--------------------------
320002101     3453543.67  
320003478     103343.56
```

user chooses two dates, 1st one is @startdate and another @enddate, 
Enddate should be determining what quarter to choose of course, if its May then it must show JUNE(6th month) and the last day of quarter.

My query was something like this, but obviously it doesn't work, i tried mixing up things in data functions

```
 SELECT bal.AccountNo,acc.AccountName ,
 DATEADD(quarter,DATEDIFF(quarter,0,@enddate),30) [quarter], 
SUM(bal.Sum)  [quarterlySum]
FROM dbo.Balances AS bal
INNER JOIN dbo.Accounts AS acc
ON acc.AccountNo = bal.AccountNo
WHERE (bal.BalanceDate BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate) 
GROUP BY acc.AccountName,bal.AccountNo
```

Comment: Some sample data and the query you tried would be awesome

Comment: to get then end of quarter you can use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302452/calculate-the-last-day-of-the-quarter

Comment: @xdd as you see, i have date - may, which is already 2nd quarter, and i need to show balance sum for 2nd quarter and end date of the month particularly

Comment: You want three columns in your output like that: "320002101 100500.67 06/30/2017"? Or you want the column named as '06/30/2017'?

Comment: The column name will be the 'Date' - of the end of the quarter

Comment: in your 'output' you don't show the column 'Date'. And the last question: why do you need EndDate if you want the Balance on the end of Quarter?

Comment: Well, if you say i dont need enddate, lets try without enddate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure below will work, but it's worth to give a go:

```
declare @startdate date = (select getdate()- 60 )
declare @enddate date = (select getdate() - 30)
select @startdate, @enddate

declare @sql nvarchar(1000)
set @sql = 
    'SELECT bal.AccountNo,
        SUM(bal.Sum) as ''' +  replace(convert(nvarchar(10), DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, @enddate) +1, 0)), 101), '/', '') +'''
        INNER JOIN dbo.Accounts AS acc
        ON acc.AccountNo = bal.AccountNo
    WHERE (bal.BalanceDate BETWEEN ''' + convert(varchar, @startdate, 101) + ''' AND ''' + convert(varchar, @enddate, 101) +''')
    GROUP BY acc.AccountName'

print @sql
exec (@sql)
```

I do not think so there is another way than doing this dynamically as above.

Comment: Do you need to add ' and + after SUM(bal.sum)

Comment: @Tilek N. Don't think so, current code should work. Did you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

My question was to get the end of the quarter from currentdate, and also not just end of the quarter, but the end of the month of the end of the quarter from currentdate

And here is the code, i used to retrieve my data

```
DECLARE @startdate DATE; SET @startdate='5/2/2017';
DECLARE @enddate DATE; SET @enddate='6/13/2017'   
DECLARE @datatype VARCHAR; SET @datatype=3;

SELECT bal.AccountNo,acc.AccountName ,
CASE @datatype WHEN 3 THEN SUM(bal.Sumn)END AS [balance] 
FROM dbo.Balances AS bal
INNER JOIN dbo.Accounts AS acc
ON acc.AccountNo = bal.AccountNo
WHERE (bal.BalanceDate BETWEEN   convert(varchar, @startdate, 101)   AND   
convert(varchar, @enddate, 101))
GROUP BY acc.AccountName,bal.AccountNo
```